# Tortoise SVN - "Restore after commit" option not available

Tags: tortoisesvn

If I recall correctly (from the Tortoise SVN's commit log I saw), Tortoise SVN added this feature in January where you can edit a file and have TSVN restore it after commit (aka Commit only parts of a file).

TSVN's documentation also lists this feature now:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html

I am running latest version of TSVN (1.7.6) on a Win 7 64 bit machine, but I cannot see this option anywhere while committing a file. Am I missing something, or has this feature not been shipped??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#releases).

Answer (score 2):

[According to tortoise FAQ Page](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#releases)

**I was told that issue/bug X was fixed in rXXX, but the latest release still doesn't have this implemented/fixed?**

Our release policy is to never introduce new features or resource changes on the stable branch. We work on the trunk, where we fix bugs, introduce new features or change the behavior of features. Only important bugfixes are merged back to the stable branch, and the stable branch is where we create our releases from.

We have this policy to prevent getting new bugs into the stable branch. After all, it's called the stable branch.

Your requested feature/reported bug, even though it is fixed/implemented on trunk was not merged back to the stable branch due to this policy. That's why you don't see the change in the latest release.